# How can I set a batch file to pic up a txt file and put some data in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, batch-file, text-files

How can I set a batch file to pic up a txt file and put some data in mySQL database.
I need to set up a process to run every hour and read a txt file and put data in a mySQL data base. Should I use PHP? BAT file? Suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for this.

Basically, it allows you to run a file at given interval (every hour, or every other day, for example).

Answer (score 1):

depends on which operation system you are using because crontab implies hey has a linux server